# Why is the general linear group a smooth manifold?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

First of all, any norm $||\cdot||$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ induces a metric $d(a,b):=||a-b||$. This metric then gives rise to a metric topology on $V$ and this topology makes $V$ a topological manifold. All good here.

The space of $n \times n$ matrices $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ with real entries is a finite dimensional real vector space. Now, the argument goes like this: $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ so it is also a topological manifold.

The thing is, how do you know $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is open? What norm are we using here?

Comment: It doesn't matter: any two norms on a finite-dimensional real vector space are equivalent.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, what? This result is so strong! where can I find this theorem?

Comment: $GL(n, \mathbb R)=\det^{-1}(\mathbb R-\{0\})$ where $\det: M(n, \mathbb R)\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is the determinant function.

Comment: @PtF, thanks! do you know where can I find the theorem stated in Lord Shark the Unknown's comment above?

Comment: Check the book "Functional Analysis" by Irvin Kreyszig. I'm almost sure he proves that statement.

Comment: @PtF Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

It is the inverse image of $\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}}$ (which is open) under the continuous map that maps the matrices in $Ml(n,\mathbb{R})$ to the determinant. And the inverse image is open (continuity).